# VS2010 build order affects whether or not my build succeeds

Tags: visual-studio, oracle

I have an application written in Pro*C (C with embedded Oracle SQL) that I had building in VS2008 using custom build files to do the preprocessing. The source is in .m4 format (for legacy reasons - I will at some point get rid of this but it's not high on my priority list). The .m4 gets processed by the M4 utility into .pc (Pro*C files), which then get converted into .C files by the Oracle ProC utility.

We have clients that are using both Oracle 10 and Oracle 11 clients, so I have one project set up for each database version since they need to be built with different Oracle versions. Both projects use the same source code - the only difference is in the Rule files.

When using VS2008, I never had any problems with this process. When I moved the project to VS2010 (rules files converted to .xml, .props, and .targets files), I started getting a build error where my custom build rule was returning a bad code for one of the projects.

What's interesting is that every other time I "Rebuild All", the project that fails and the project succeeds switches (i.e. first time oracle10 project succeeds and oracle11 project fails, second time oracle10 fails and oracle11 succeeds). The project that succeeds reliably alternates each time I build, though it seems to always be the first project to process (not sure why Visual Studio wouldn't start with the same project each time).

If I build each project individually, I don't have any problems. If I create a solution-level project dependency, regardless of which project references which, I don't have any problems.

So despite the fact that I've found a work-around, I'm curious about what was causing this issue to begin with.

PS - I'm pretty new to StackOverflow, so I apologize in advance if I missed anything in asking this question. Let me know if there's anything else I could provide to help solve the issue.

Comment: Sounds to me you've got a problem with parallel builds.  You can turn that off with Tools + Options.  The real fix is to set the project dependencies correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks - I think that is exactly what is happening. I didn't realize that VS did parallel builds. The two projects are not truly dependent on each other, but Visual Studio must be trying to call the M4 preprocessor twice at the same time.